# How to use modules in a argonDash dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I've just discovered these amazing packages called argonR and argonDash, but ,unfortunatly, I haven't had succes so far using modules with it. Is it possible?

I've tried to ns it, but it doesnt work. It works locally, but It is not able to change tabs when deployed.

```
# rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(argonR)
library(argonDash)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyjs)

# Modules
source("sidebar.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("navbar.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("header.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("footer.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_home.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_stats.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_prob.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_stat_econ.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_econometria.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_ML.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_quiz.R", encoding = "utf8")
source("R/mod_sobre.R", encoding = "utf8")

# App
ui <- argonDashPage(
  title = "TCM",
  author = "Guilherme",
  description = "Guig's TCM",

  sidebar = argonDashSidebar(
    vertical = TRUE,
    skin = "light",
    background = "white",
    size = "md",
    side = "left",
    id = "my_sidebar",
    brand_url = "http://www.google.com",
    # brand_logo = "https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-design-system/assets/img/brand/blue.png",
    # brand_logo = ,
    brand_logo = "https://kdrt.org/sites/default/files/styles/adaptive/public/Rocket%20Radio%20program%20picture.png?itok=-FHCim8R",

    argonSidebarHeader(title = "Menu Principal"),
    argonSidebarMenu(
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "home_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Home"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "stats_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Estatística"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "prob_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Probabilidade"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "stat_econ_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Estatística Econômica"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "econometria_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Econometria"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "ML_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Machine Learning"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "quiz_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Quiz"
      ),
      argonSidebarItem(
        tabName = "sobre_tab",
        style="text-align:center",
        "Sobre"
      )
    ),
    argonSidebarDivider(),
    argonSidebarHeader(title = "@TCM  Versão 0.1")
  ),

  navbar = argonDashNavbar(
    argonDropNav(
      title = "Powered by R",
      # src = "https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard/assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg",
      src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCLcatfAURCtGHsd71IjruuQqMXjezkwwjZR5inocuNz0imUF5sA",
      orientation = "right",
      argonDropNavTitle(title = "Este app é formado por"),
      argonDropNavItem(
        title = "R",
        src = "https://www.r-project.org/",
        icon = argonIcon("single-02")
      ),
      argonDropNavItem(
        title = "RStudio",
        src = "https://rstudio.com/",
        icon = argonIcon("settings-gear-65")
      ),
      argonDropNavDivider(),
      argonDropNavItem(
        title = "Guigo's código",
        src = "#",
        icon = argonIcon("calendar-grid-58")
      )
    )
  ),

  header = argonDashHeader(
    gradient = TRUE,
    color = "primary",
    separator = TRUE,
    separator_color = "secondary"#,
    # argonCard(
    #   title = "Olá, visitante!",
    #   src = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/guilherme-viegas-1b5b0495/",
    #   hover_lift = TRUE,
    #   shadow = TRUE,
    #   shadow_size = NULL,
    #   hover_shadow = FALSE,
    #   border_level = 0,
    #   # icon = argonIcon("atom"),
    #   icon = "https://scontent.ffln1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13669798_1073355219425752_3359245208514920392_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_oc=AQk0e2H7_Cjzdx97Vq_sl2v_JrdqSZBK5oFe6Kj6VGu_OKOvO7zFTwta02RVm-Bz8Ck&_nc_ht=scontent.ffln1-1.fna&oh=bad62632b291289b4338d3aec456cbe2&oe=5E2B61E2",
    #   status = "primary",
    #   background_color = NULL,
    #   gradient = FALSE, 
    #   floating = FALSE,
    #   "Seja muito bem vindo.\nEste é meu cartão, tome."
    # )
  ),

  body = argonDashBody(
    argonTabItems(

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "home_tab",
        mod_home_ui("home_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "stats_tab",
        mod_stats_ui("stats_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "prob_tab",
        mod_prob_ui("prob_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "stat_econ_tab",
        mod_stat_econ_ui("stat_econ_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "econometria_tab",
        mod_econometria_ui("econometria_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "ML_tab",
        mod_ML_ui("ML_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "quiz_tab",
        mod_quiz_ui("quiz_ui_1")
      ),

      argonTabItem(
        tabName = "sobre_tab",
        mod_sobre_ui("sobre_ui_1")
      )

    )
  ),
  footer = argonDashFooter(
    copyrights = "@Guilherme Viegas, 2019",
    src = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/guilherme-viegas-1b5b0495/",
    argonFooterMenu(
      argonFooterItem("Linkedin", src = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/guilherme-viegas-1b5b0495/"),
      argonFooterItem("Github", src = "https://github.com/Gui-go"),
      argonFooterItem("Facebook", src = "https://www.facebook.com/guilherme.viegas.90"),
      argonFooterItem("Instagram", src = "https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-design-system/index.html")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # observeEvent(input$my_sidebar, {
  #   if (input$my_sidebar != "sobre") { 
  #     updateTabItems(session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "quiz") 
  #   }
  # })

  callModule(mod_home_server, "home_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_stats_server, "stats_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_prob_server, "prob_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_stat_econ_server, "stat_econ_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_econometria_server, "econometria_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_ML_server, "ML_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_quiz_server, "quiz_ui_1")
  callModule(mod_sobre_server, "sobre_ui_1")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Although It works locally, when I deploy it, It simple doesnt work online. In other words, it works fine locally, but when deplyed it simple doesnt change the tabs. Weird right?

Comment: this is hard to help with as we cannot reproduce this... can you make a minimal, reproducible example using only the necessary code to recreate the error?

Comment: I've edited a bit so I could try and use modules, but the author of the package has done this code:
https://github.com/RinteRface/argonDash/blob/master/inst/examples/gallery/app.R
Perhaps you could reproduce ir from his code.
The thing is, It would be great if I could use modules as tabs in the app, as in any ordinary shiny app.

Comment: If it works locally, but not on your server then I would assume that modules are working with argon and that the error lies somewhere on your shiny server.

Comment: It's not the case. I tried simple codes just to make sure.
My guess is that this new argonDash don't work well with modules. In their examples, they use only one server, which is in the main app script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. As for October 2019, the CRAN package version does not allow change of tabs (It's a bug). This error was corrected in their Github package version, and soon will be on CRAN as well. It's just a bug, happens...

Answer (score 0):

you can use modules like this!

I suppose global.R and app.R are in the same directory.

## global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(argonR)
library(argonDash)
```

## app.R

```
source(file.path("global.R"),  local = TRUE)$value

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = argonDashPage(
  title = "Argon App", 
description = "Your description", 
author = "You",
navbar = argonDashNavbar(), 
sidebar = argonDashSidebar(
  id = "sidebar", 
  side = "left",
  size = "md", 
  skin = "light",
  background = "white",
  argonSidebarMenu(
    argonSidebarItem(
      tabName = "Tab1",
      icon = argonIcon(name = "circle-08", color = "success"),
      "Tab 1"
    ),
    argonSidebarItem(
      tabName = "Tab2",
      icon = argonIcon(name = "atom", color = "success"),
      "Tab 2"
    )
  )
), 
header = argonDashHeader(), 
body = argonDashBody(
  argonTabItems(
    argonTabItem(
      tabName = "Tab1",
      argonCard(
        status = "primary",
        width = 12,
        title = "Card 1",
        hover_lift = TRUE,
        shadow = TRUE,
        icon = argonIcon("check-bold"),
        src = "#",
        "Argon is a great free UI package based on Bootstrap 4 
        that includes the most important components and features."
      )
    ),
    argonTabItem(
      tabName = "Tab2",
      argonBadge(
        text = "My badge",
        src = "https://www.google.com",
        pill = FALSE,
        status = "success"
      )
    )
  )
),
footer = argonDashFooter(copyrights = "Yourself")
),
 server = function(input, output, session) {

  }
)
```

The strategy has been fully inspired from https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/split-code